# Renumbering of a column and replace of lines in the file

Tags: bash, perl

I have a file as the following. For 1ABC lines, I want to replace 1.line to 3.line, 2.line to 1.line, 3.line to 4.line and 4.line to 2.line. I want to do the same thing for 2ABC lines (in real file I have 1ABC,2ABC,3ABC...1000ABC lines). After replacing lines, I should renumber the 3.column. How can I do this (I have to preserve the spacing between the columns in the output file)?

Input file:

```
1ABC     C1    1   0.349  
1ABC     H2    2   0.123   
1ABC     O1    3   0.217  
1ABC     H4    4   0.180  
2ABC     C1    5   2.015 
2ABC     H2    6   0.573     
2ABC     O1    7   1.929    
2ABC     H4    8   1.867
```

Requested output:

```
1ABC     H2    1   0.123   
1ABC     H4    2   0.180 
1ABC     C1    3   0.349   
1ABC     O1    4   0.217
2ABC     H2    5   0.573    
2ABC     H4    6   1.867  
2ABC     C1    7   2.015  
2ABC     O1    8   1.929
```

Comment: Is bash the only option that you are looking for ? Have you explored python or other scripting langugage ?

Comment: @vijayalakshmid No. Bash is not the only option. I just edited "Tags". I don't know python very well.  I also know perl but not too much. But I couldn't do it using perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script will change the third column of the input file into the number that you require and the output should be sorted for the third field.

1. Script : torun.sh

filename="input.txt"

```
cat input.txt | while read line
do
key=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
res=`echo $key % 4 | bc`
newvalue=$key
if [ $res -eq "0" ]
then
        newvalue=`expr $key - 2`
fi
if [ $res -eq "1" ]
then
        newvalue=`expr $key + 2`
fi
if [ $res -eq "2" ]
then
        newvalue=`expr $key - 1`
fi
if [ $res -eq "3" ]
then
        newvalue=`expr $key + 1`
fi
echo $line | awk -v v1="$newvalue" '{$3=v1; print}'
```

done

2. How to run : ./tunrun.sh | sort -k 3
3. Please note that awk changes the delimiter of the column to single space. I am not sure whether multiple space or tab is your delimiter. We can easily fix the script to properly display the line with the correct delimiter once you confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged it as perl, and I see no perl answer yet, so here's how I'd do it:

It *looks* like what you're doing is having a fixed order based on second column. Is that correct? Specifically H2, H4, C1, O1.

Sorting by first column, then that ordering, and then having the third column as - basically - line number - you get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %results;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $code, $OH, $index, $value ) = split;
    $results{$code}{$OH} = $value;
}

my $rank         = 1;
my @output_order = qw ( H2 H4 C1 O1 );

foreach my $code ( sort keys %results ) {
    foreach my $OH (@output_order) {
        print join( "\t", $code, $OH, $rank++, $results{$code}{$OH} ), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__ 
1ABC     C1    1   0.349  
1ABC     H2    2   0.123   
1ABC     O1    3   0.217  
1ABC     H4    4   0.180  
2ABC     C1    5   2.015 
2ABC     H2    6   0.573     
2ABC     O1    7   1.929    
2ABC     H4    8   1.867
```

Which will print:

```
1ABC    H2  1   0.123
1ABC    H4  2   0.180
1ABC    C1  3   0.349
1ABC    O1  4   0.217
2ABC    H2  5   0.573
2ABC    H4  6   1.867
2ABC    C1  7   2.015
2ABC    O1  8   1.929
```

Comment: it works. Thanks. I have a small question. You have used this parenthesis `{}` a few times. What does this parenthesis in perl? I am a new user. I want to learn. Sorry.

Comment: If you mean: `$results{$code}` then this is accessing a `hash` or associative array  - which is a set of key-value pairs and one of the features that sets perl apart from other languages. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to just read the four lines in and then print them back out in the modified order.

```
n=1

while read -r a1 b1 c1 d1 &&
      read -r a2 b2 c2 d2 &&
      read -r a3 b3 c3 d3 &&
      read -r a4 b4 c4 d4
do
    printf '%-8s %-5s %-3s %s\n' "$a2" "$b2" "$((n++))" "$d2"
    printf '%-8s %-5s %-3s %s\n' "$a4" "$b4" "$((n++))" "$d4"
    printf '%-8s %-5s %-3s %s\n' "$a1" "$b1" "$((n++))" "$d1"
    printf '%-8s %-5s %-3s %s\n' "$a3" "$b3" "$((n++))" "$d3"
done
```

This suffers from excessive repetitiveness, generally a code smell. A bit more elegant approach would be to split up the reordering and the renumbering into separate stages.

```
reorder() {    
    while read -r l1 && read -r l2 && read -r l3 && read -r l4; do
        printf '%s\n' "$l2" "$l4" "$l1" "$l3"
    done
}

renumber() {
    awk '{ $3 = ++n; print }'
}

reorder < in.txt | renumber > out.txt
```

Note that this does not preserve the spacing between the columns.